# Percent value in y axis of Column Chart Microsoft chart control

Tags: c#, microsoft-chart-controls

I am trying to get Column charts, where I need to have percentage value in y axis and should recalculate and scale.

I have seen some suggestion to assign minimum and maximum value ( `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum=0`) but it's not adjusting the column height according to the percentage. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is what I have done so far

```
 foreach (var value in labels)
   {

     chart.Legends[value].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
     chart.Legends[value].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
     chart.Series[value].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
     chart.Series[value].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
     chart.Series[value].Label = "#PERCENT{P0}";

     chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
     chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled =false;
     chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum=0;
      // chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();

      chart.BringToFront();

      if (count == 0 && comp.Value != null)
        chart.Series[value].Points.Add(comp.Value[0]);
      else if (count >= 1 && comp.Value != null && comp.Value.Count() > count)
        chart.Series[value].Points.Add(comp.Value[count]);
      else
        chart.Series[value].Points.Add(0);

          count++;
}
```

[image: column chart]
The Y axis should show the percentage and the columns height should be adjusted to the y axis percentage value.

Comment: Can you include an image that shows what you want?

Comment: @TaW added image. Please check and let e know if you have a solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that shows all sorts of info about the data in the chart:

- The X&Y-Values in a `ToolTip`
- The percentages of the the values against the total on the `Columns`
- The percentage against the maximum at the `Y-Axis`

[image]

```
Series S = chart1.Series[0];
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Axis AY = CA.AxisY;

S.Points.AddXY(1, 10);      S.Points.AddXY(2, 40);
S.Points.AddXY(3, 50);      S.Points.AddXY(4, 100);
S.Points.AddXY(5, 111);  

S.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
S.Label = "#PERCENT{P0}";

S.ToolTip = "#VALX{#.##}" + " : " + "#VALY1{#.##}";

double max = S.Points.Max(x => x.YValues[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < S.Points.Count; i++)
{
    DataPoint dp =  S.Points[i];
    double y0 = S.Points[i].YValues[0];
    AY.CustomLabels.Add(y0, y0 + 1, (y0 / max * 100f).ToString("0.0") + "%");
}
```

Of course you can change it all around as you please..